# Six of one maybe?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

As usual from me a Venn-based challenge. The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions. There are seven tiles. Place one tile in each region so that the tiles in any one ellipse can be re-arranged to solve the corresponding clue.

[image]

Comment: I get the same as Jafe. Am I the only one who tore little pieces of paper as the tiles?

Comment: I suppose the answer is yes, but can those be made so that the “nonshared” tiles make one word when joined together? Do you have such an example?

Comment: @PierrePaquette Is that a puzzle in itself? "The only one"?

Comment: @m4n0: No, it was just a question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This looks like

> Viewers: **AUDIENCE**
>  One man one horse? **CENTAURS** (as in two half-horse half-men, making one whole man and one whole horse in total?)
>  Verdict: **SENTENCE**

Filled-in diagram

> [image]